# Javascript repeat button click based on input variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button click (send) happen times the amount the user filles in an input form (howmany). My problem is that the click is not happening. What is going wrong, there are no error logs. The logs say clicked times the input variable.. But the button click only happends once. The inputs are in a form that submits after the click.

So in short my question: I need javascript (or an other solution) to submit my button with id 'send' times the number the user filles in id 'howmany'. So when the user puts in 10 the button should be submitted only 10 times and than stop untill the user presses the button again.

```
<tr><td class="footer">Hire for (hours): </td><td class="footer"><input type="number" value="1"  onClick="this.select()" name="findtime" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="footer">How many times: </td><td class="footer"><input type="number" value="1"  onClick="this.select()" id="howmany" name="howmany" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="footer"></td><td class="footer"><input class="example_c" type="submit" id="send" name="send" onclick="myFunction()" value="Hire private detective"></td></tr>

<script language="javascript">
 function myFunction() {
  const timesToClick = document.getElementById("howmany").value;
  for (let i = 0; i < timesToClick; ++i) {
    document.getElementById("send").click();
    console.log('clicked');
  }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: You must parse the input as a number. Now its just a string. Try `const timesToClick = Number(document.getElementById("howmany").value);`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, same result :(. the clicks are not happening 6 times like i filled in. only once, the log however shows no errors

Comment: You are clicking the same element again on which onclick myFunction is triggring. So clicks will be twice of original call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use setTimeOut to do the iteration

Please run the code snippet,click "start" to see the effect

```js
function realclick(){
console.log('clicked');
document.getElementById("send").click();
}


function myFunction() {

if (document.getElementById("howmanyleft").value =="") {
document.getElementById("howmanyleft").value=document.getElementById("howmany").value;
}

if (document.getElementById("howmanyleft").value > 0) {
setTimeout(function(){ realclick(); }, 200);
document.getElementById("howmanyleft").value=(document.getElementById("howmanyleft").value *1) -1;
 }
else
{
document.getElementById("howmanyleft").value ="";
}
 
}
```

```html
  
<table>
<tr><td class="footer">Hire for (hours): </td><td class="footer">
<input type="number" value="1"  onClick="this.select()" name="findtime" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="footer">How many times: </td><td class="footer">
<input type="number" value="5"  onClick="this.select()" id="howmany" name="howmany" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input  value=""   id="howmanyleft" id="howmanyleft" size="20" readonly type=hidden></td></tr>


<tr><td class="footer"></td>
<td class="footer">
<input class="example_c" type="submit" id="send" name="send" onclick="myFunction()" value="Start"></td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But also this is not actually clicking the button :(. It clicks only when i click, than it should click again times the value that was put in. All it does is count down :(

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button has an onclick function is myFunction. So when you click the send button, myFunction function is triggered and click the send button again. So the function is running twice. You can set a variable for triggering like below.

```js
var isTriggered = false;
function myFunction() {
  console.log('clicked');
    if (!isTriggered) {
        const timesToClick = document.getElementById("howmany").value;
      isTriggered = true;
      for (let i = 0; i < timesToClick; i++) {
        document.getElementById("send").click();
      }  
      isTriggered = false;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<tr><td class="footer">Hire for (hours): </td><td class="footer"><input type="number" value="1"  onClick="this.select()" name="findtime" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="footer">How many times: </td><td class="footer"><input type="number" value="1"  onClick="this.select()" id="howmany" name="howmany" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="footer"></td><td class="footer"><input class="example_c" type="submit" id="send" name="send" onclick="myFunction()" value="Hire private detective"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the idea is that the function realy clicks the submit button. In logs the clicks. But the actual click is not happening more than one time. So this answer is not helping me yet :(

Comment: The bottom submits a form. The form is only submitted when i click it. The idea is that the button is clicked and submits that form times the value amount.

Comment: OK the code exactly does it. When you click the button myFunction is triggered, for loop starts and the send button is clicked for each iteration. The myFunction function works again as it is clicked on each iteration. I edited my answer to show it more clearly.